# Where is "Opacity" in CompizConfig settings manager?

Tags: ccsm

I can't find the Opacity in Compiz, "No matches found".

In Accessibility, I only have "Enhanced Zoom Desktop", i don't have Opacity.

Comment: search directly in filter..

Answer (score 2):

Try to install compiz plugins,to do that run the below command on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-default
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra
```

Or

Remove the ccsm completely and reinstall it,

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Answer (score 1):

Check under the Accessibility menu.  See image below.

[image]